# Interaction with beamer pause and urlbordercolor of hyperref results in a graphical glitch

Tags: beamer, hyperref, urls, pause

I noticed a weird interaction between pdfborderstyle and the pause command of beamer.
How I can get rid of it?

This code will produce a graphical glitch:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% suppresses all navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% border style will be underline of width 2pt
\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    example text

    \pause
    \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is what I see inside LaTeX Workshop built-in pdf viewer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `onlyenv` instead of a pause to make sure that the url is not there on the first overlay.

To avoid the content of the slide jumping between overlays, combine this with either a top aligned frame or an `overlayarea`.

Check carefully if your underline has any unwanted site effects on your theme. Beamer normally uses links at all kinds of places, in headlines, in footlines etc. Adding an underline there might destroy the look intended by the theme.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% suppresses all navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% border style will be underline of width 2pt
\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 2}}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    example text
    
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\baselineskip}
    \begin{onlyenv}<2->
    \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}
    \end{onlyenv}
    \end{overlayarea}    

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

Instead of enabling the underline globally, you could only do so for selected overlays. The risk for unindented side effects would be much less.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% suppresses all navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  
    \only<2->{\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 2}}}

    example text
    \pause
    
    \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you could also change the border on the first slide `\only<1>{\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 0}}}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I had already added an approach to switch it only on on the second overlay, this will be much less risky with links in foot- and headlines

Comment: "Check carefully if your underline has any unwanted site effects on your theme. Beamer normally uses links at all kinds of places, in headlines, in footlines etc." yes, this is another problem, I'm using metropolis and every section and subsection have an underline. That's another problem I couldn't resolve, but I would like not to give up about this style beacuse I like it visually

Comment: such underlines are not part of the text but added by the annotation, so they don't affect the layout (in the sense of placement of text), only the visual look.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, but they will look odd, the colours won't match the colour of the head-/footlines ...

Comment: This happen if you use `\usetheme[sectionpage=simple]{metropolis}` for example

Comment: I've used `urlbordercolor={0 .5 .5}` inside hypersetup to match the color @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: @EmanueleNardi You could avoid most problems if you wouldn't enable the underline globally but just locally around the link you actually want to be underlined, e.g. `{\only<2->{\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 2}}}
    \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}}`